# MySQL Slow query: count articles, group by category, any way to optimize?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, explain

Is there any way to optimize this query? It takes more than 2.5 secs.

```
SELECT articles.categories_id,
    COUNT(articles.id) AS count
FROM articles
WHERE articles.created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
GROUP BY articles.categories_id
ORDER BY count DESC

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `feeds_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `users_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `sefriendly` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `body` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `source` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `edited` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `fingerprint` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '1 => Feed fetched article\n2 => User submitted article',
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `keywords` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 => Passive\n1 => Active\n2 => Pending',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `categories_id` (`categories_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `feeds_id` (`feeds_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `users_id` (`users_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `fingerprint` (`fingerprint`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

I already use caching, so there is no problem in terms of code.

This is the explain sql result:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  articles    index   NULL    categories_id   4   NULL    120411  Using where; Using temporary; Using file sort
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can improve things by adding an index on `created`. This will help serve your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE articles.created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
```

It will probably be advantageous to instead create a covering index on `(created, categories_id)` so that all the data required for the query is available in the index.

Note that the value of `id` is not needed for this query because COUNT only cares if the value is NULL or NOT NULL, but `id` is defined to be NOT NULL in your table definition. It would probably be a good idea to make this explicit by using `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` instead of `COUNT(id)` as this is guaranteed to give the same result. But I would expect that MySQL is intelligent enough to make this optimization for you automatically.

I don't think that you can avoid the file sort because you are sorting on the result of an aggregation, and this cannot be indexed.

Comment: Creating and index on created only does the trick. Thanks a lot.